# How To Identify Last Active Tab On Browser

Tags: javascript, jquery, .net, dom-events

If multiple tabs are active on browser.
Lets say -

Tab-1 : google.com

Tab-2 : youtube.com

Tab-3 : Facebook.com

Now if I open my website in Tab-4 : example.com and switch to Tab-2 and then again come to Tab-4 , then on example.com (application I am building right now), I want to identify I have came there from youtube.com

How can I do it in Javascript or jQuery?

Note :-

To identify active tab I have written code :-

```
document.addEventListener("visibilitychange", function() {
      document.title = document.hidden ? "I'm away" : "I'm here";
});
```

Comment: Have you tried the script on https://stackoverflow.com/a/1060034/2943218 ?

Comment: Tabs are isolated (thank fully) - you haven't "come there from youtube.com" - you're already there.

Answer (score 1):

You don't have any way to see what window you came from as this would be a security violation.